# How to get the GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext for an AAD user?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, client

I need to create a new user in azure devops using the python client library for Azure DevOps REST API.

I wrote the following code:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.devops.v5_0.graph.models import GraphUserCreationContext
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

graph_client = connection.clients_v5_0.get_graph_client()

addAADUserContext = GraphUserCreationContext("anaya.john@mydomain.com")
print(addAADUserContext)

resp = graph_client.create_user(addAADUserContext)
print(resp)
```

I get the output:

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'storage_key': 'anaya.john@dynactionize.onmicrosoft.com'}
```

And an error occurs while calling the create_user method:

```
azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: VS860015: Must have exactly one of originId or principalName set.
```

Actually what i should pass a **GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext** to the create_user function.

I found a .NET sample which does this in a function named **AddRemoveAADUserByUPN()** :
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/Graph/UsersSample.cs

GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext is an interface in this sample. But python doesn't support interfaces.

So how can implement this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the classes like `GraphUserPrincipalNameCreationContext` aren't currently available in the python client API. They are working on it. You can track the issue here in GitHub repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/176

You can use **User Entitlements - Add** REST API for azure devops instead of it's Graph API. You can use the following python client for this purpose:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/tree/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_0/member_entitlement_management

You can refer to the sample given in the following question to know about how to use the mentioned python client :

[Unable to deserialize to object: type, KeyError: ' key: int; value: str '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665624/unable-to-deserialize-to-object-type-keyerror-key-int-value-str)